# Dialog button command not being called

Tags: customization, acumatica

This should be simple.  I have a custom dialog with some data fields, and an OK button.  I want the OK button to perform a save of the fields as well as other processing.  I’ve tried many things, but so far, my OK button doesn’t perform my associated code.  I defined a new dialog within the page editor.  I added an action button that appears on the menu, and it opens my dialog just fine via button command delegate method and the AskExt() method of the view.  But my OK button just closes the dialog and seemingly does nothing else.  I have tried setting breakpoints after the OK is returned:

```
if (view.AskExt("viewPanel", true) == WebDialogResult.OK)
{
    // other code here, with a breakpoint
}
else
{
    // other code here, with a breakpoint
{
```

and no breakpoints are hit.  I also set the dialog button’s AutoCallback command to a custom method with a breakpoint.  I tried a method signature of both protected void () that matches a button action delegate and a public IEnumerable (PXAdapter), and breakpoint inside these also do not get hit.

I’m assuming there’s something very simple I’m missing, which is unfortunately often the case with such UI behavioral issues, but I’ve tried a combination of many things and no luck yet, so I thought I would run it by the community for some help.

My dialog OK button settings look like this:

[image]

Does anything obvious jump out?

**[Update on 7/16/23]**: This is in my aspx.  My PXFormView DataMember is the same as the PXSmartPanel Key.

```
<px:PXSmartPanel runat="server" ID="PanelReadMe" Caption="read.me" CaptionVisible="True" LoadOnDemand="True" AllowResize="True" HideAfterAction="True" AcceptButtonID="btnSave" CancelButtonID="btnCancel" CloseButtonDialogResult="Cancel" Width="1100" Height="575" AutoRepaint="True" AutoReload="True" Key="ReadMeProject" AutoCallBack-Enabled="True" AutoCallBack-Target="frmReadMeDlg" AutoCallBack-Command="ReadMeSave" AutoCallBack-Behavior-CommitChanges="True" AutoCallBack-Behavior-PostData="Page">
<px:PXFormView runat="server" ID="frmReadMeDlg" DataMember="ReadMeProject" Caption="Read.Me" CaptionVisible="False" DataSourceID="ds" NoteIndicator="False" ActivityIndicator="False" Width="1100" Height="550">
    <Template>
        <px:PXSelector runat="server" ID="CstPXSelector24" DataField="Name" Enabled="False" />
        <px:PXTextEdit runat="server" ID="CstPXTextEdit26" DataField="Description" Enabled="False" />
        <px:PXRichTextEdit runat="server" DataField="UsrReadMe" ID="edReadMe" Height="600" Width="1100">
            <AutoSize Container="Parent" Enabled="True" MinHeight="500" MinWidth="950" />
        </px:PXRichTextEdit>
        <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" ID="CstPXLayoutRule8" StartRow="True" />
        <px:PXPanel runat="server" ID="PanelButtons" SkinID="Buttons">
            <px:PXButton runat="server" ID="PanelButtonsOK" DialogResult="OK" Text="OK" PopupPanel="PanelReadMe">
                <AutoCallBack Command="readMeSave" Target="ds" ActiveBehavior="True" Enabled="True">
                    <Behavior PostData="Page" CommitChanges="True" />
                </AutoCallBack>
            </px:PXButton>
            <px:PXButton runat="server" ID="PanelButtonsCancel" Text="Cancel" DialogResult="Cancel" PopupPanel="PanelReadMe">
                <AutoCallBack Command="readMeCancel" Enabled="True" Target="ds" />
            </px:PXButton>
        </px:PXPanel>
    </Template>
    <AutoSize Container="Parent" />
</px:PXFormView>
</px:PXSmartPanel>
```

Comment: Just wanted to circle back and let those who might be interested know how I resolved this…  I ended up starting over a bit and creating a new dialog.  And instead of calling view.AskExt() at all in my toolbar button callback method to popup a dialog, I set the button’s PopupPanel UI property to the dialog’s ID.  After doing this, the dialog still pops open as needed, and the dialog button’s callback command then actually called my method as expected.  Unfortunately, I don’t know why I couldn’t get the initial way to work, but I got it working anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is a button from a working smart panel:

```
<px:PXButton runat="server" ID="Button46" DialogResult="OK" Text="OK" />
```

Maybe you forgot to set the Key? In my example DialogFilter is the View (Data Member) assigned to PanelForm form on the smart panel.

```
<px:PXSmartPanel runat="server" ID="SmartPanel40" LoadOnDemand="True" Key="DialogFilter" AutoCallBack-Target="PanelForm" AutoCallBack-Command="Refresh" AutoCallBack-Enabled="True">
```

Update: Also, you can try to call the panel without any parameter:

```
if (view.AskExt() == WebDialogResult.OK)
```

Comment: I added my .aspx.  The Key should be correct.

Comment: I added an update. If it won't work I will try to replicate your issue in my instance. What version of Acumatica do you use?